# How to display Most Recently Read 10 Posts by a logged in user in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress site where users can register and maintain their profile. 
One of the main function of the logged in users is displaying their most RECENTLY READ 20 or 10 posts on their profile. 
I tried this but that's not working perfectly and displays only one post.

```
add_action('get_header','save_single_posts_to_usermeta');

function save_single_posts_to_usermeta(){
   if(is_single() && is_user_logged_in()){
      $user_id = get_current_user_id();
      $read_posts = get_user_meta($user_id,'_read_posts',true);
      $most_recent_read_post = get_user_meta($user_id,'_most_recent_post',true);
      if(!is_array($read_posts)){
         $read_posts = array();
      }
      if(!isset($read_posts[get_the_ID()])){
         $read_posts[get_the_ID()] = 1;
      } else {
         $read_posts[get_the_ID()] = $read_posts[get_the_ID()]+1;
      }
      update_user_meta($user_id,'_most_recent_post',get_the_ID());
      update_user_meta($user_id,'_read_posts',$read_posts);
   }
}


add_shortcode('most_recent_read_post','show_most_recent_read_post');

function show_most_recent_read_post($args=array()){
   if(is_user_logged_in()){
      $user_id = get_current_user_id();
      $last_read_post = get_user_meta($user_id,'_most_recent_post',true);
      if($last_read_post){
         return "Last Read Post:".get_the_title((int)$last_read_post);
      } else {
         return "No posts were read yet!";
      }
   } else {
      return "You must be logged in to view your last read post";
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Read about WordPress Loop and WP_Query https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: if you can help me out to fix the above code i would be a great help!